# ZipFile corrupted after downloading using Java

Tags: java, applet

Downloaded Zip files using Java, when it's open saying that Can't open.
Want to know what is the pblm?
Is it because of less memory?

Here is the code for downloading zipFiles

```
try {
    for(int i=0;i<URL_LOCATION.length;i++) {
        url = new URL(URL_LOCATION[i]);
        connection = url.openConnection(); 
        stream = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        int available = stream.available();
        b = new byte[available];
        stream.read(b);
        File file = new File(LOCAL_FILE[i]);
        OutputStream out  = new FileOutputStream(file);
        out.write(b);
        }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println(e.toString());
}
```

Soln for this:  Refered Link is  [How to download and save a file from Internet using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921262/how-to-download-and-save-a-file-from-internet-using-java)

```
BufferedInputStream in = null;
FileOutputStream fout = null;
try
{                                                                                                 
in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(urlString).openStream());
fout = new FileOutputStream(filename);
byte data[] = new byte[1024];
int count;
while ((count = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1)
{
 fout.write(data, 0, count);
}
}
finally
{
if (in != null)
in.close();
if (fout != null)
fout.close();
}
```

Comment: You used java to create zipfile? Share the code.

Comment: yeah used zipFile and tried ZipInputStream also.I already have zipFiles in wampserver. Want to download that files using zipFile.

Comment: Add some code, with a stack trace please

Comment: downloaded everything is fine, but not able to open that downloaded files.

Comment: Modify your question to include the code please.

Comment: Do modify question with codes or else it goes unnoticed with downvotes.

Comment: Is it possible that the zip file is opened in another program?

Answer (score 2):

You are using the available()-call to determine how many bytes to read. Thats blatantly wrong (see javadoc of InputStream for details). available() only tells you about data immediately available, not about the real stream length.

You need a *loop* and read from the stream until it return -1 (for EndOfStream) as number of bytes read.

I recommend you review the tutorial on streams: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/bytestreams.html

Comment: No tried that too. Not working. Why downloaded zip files are corrupted? Not able to open?